# How does the ER model look like for @Embedded classes?

Tags: java, jpa

When I use an @Embedded class in Java / JPA, how is this mirrored in the database?
For instance, if I have an `@Entity User` with an `@Embedded @Entity Address`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User {
    @ID
    private Long u_id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Embedded
    private Address address;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="Address")
public class Address {

    @Column(name="street")
    private String street;

    @Column(name="zip")
    private String zipcode;

    ....
}
```

Will this result in two tables referenced using a foreign key or will there be just ONE table containing aLL columns of both entities (what would be not well normalized)?

Comment: Why not log in to your database and check? Or enable printing of SQL statements in the app? It's possible that it depends on the database vendor, of course.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't use `@Embedded` and `@Entity` together. Your class `Address` must be marked as `@Embeddable`.

Then.

1. If you are using `@Embedded` and `@Embeddable` - it will one table with columns of both classes.
2. If you are using `@Entity` and  `@OneToMany` (or `@OneToOne`, `@ManyToOne`, `@ManyToMany`) it will be different tables;